# Define Column Values and relevant values Populate data Field in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am Trying to do a Matrix Style Report , where the Rows get Populated from the Query.

Can we Give Values in the Column Field(These are Row Values from the Query) and the data gets Populated from the Query itself.

Why I want to do this is, the query does not show the row if the Value that I want to display in the column field on the report is Null. And Hence in return cannot Display it on the report if the Query itself Does not have the value.

[image]

Now there are No values for any member in the Group, the transfers field will not show up. But it has show with a value 0 in all the columns with Row Members.

**EDIT:**

My query returns a table like this .  Parameter: 'YEAR'

---

```
Group      Group_Items   EMP_ID           Status

Group1      Alpha            1           Continuing
Group1      Alpha            2           Continuing
Group1      Alpha            6           Continuing
Group1      Beta             8           First Time
Group1      Beta             11          Continuing
Group1      Gamma            14          First Time
Group1      Gammma           15          First Time
Group1      Gamma            10          First Time
Group1      Zeta             12          Continuing
Group1      Zeta             23          Continuing
Group1      Zeta             44          Continuing
Group1      Zeta             56          First Time
```

So I want to know how we can put this in the BI and count(Emp_ID) according to First Time, Transfer and Continuing. There is transfer value sometimes , but have to show it all the time and if no values come up we have to show it as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for *NULL*/non-existent values in the transfer cell by using an expression like:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!Transfer.Value))
  , 0
  , Sum(Fields!Transfer.Value))
```

This will display *0* if there is are no values in that row/group or they're all *NULL*.

More logic can be added to the first section of the `IIf` statement if required.